# How to simulate iOS UITableView grouped sections in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way of showing a ListView in Xamarin.Forms that looks like iOS UITableView with grouped sections? Including the spacing between sections. Or maybe there is a better way than using ListView to simulate iOS UITableView with grouped sections. I want the solution using Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: see my answer here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357041/xamarin-forms-how-to-access-the-collection-used-in-listview-itemtemplate-within/45365189#45365189 ,is it you want ?

Comment: I think It's better to use TableView from Xamarin.Forms. Thanks anyway.